# Date.toLocaleString does not work properly

Tags: node.js, date

So i am setting up an api that sends me an email on user submission

It adds a date to the email as such

```
const date = new Date().toLocaleString("en-GB", {
    timeZone: "Europe/Athensli",
  });
  const mailMe = {
    from: process.env.EMAIL,
    to: process.env.MYEMAIL,
    subject: "New Message",
    html: `<p>Name: ${name}</p>
        <p>Date: ${date}</p>
        <p>Email: ${email}</p>
        <p>Company: ${company}</p>
        <p>Message: ${message}</p>`,
  };
```

The thing is, the email comes with everything looking good but "undefined" in the date field

Running the line in node terminal returns

```
>let dt = new Date().toLocaleString("en-GB", {timezone: "Europe/Athens",}); console.log(dt);
18/09/2023, 12:29:32
undefined
```

While "new Date().toLocaleString("en-GB", {timezone: "Europe/Athens",});" by itself returns the expected
'18/09/2023, 12:29:32'

Can anyone help me understand what i am missing?

As far as looking it up goes it should be ok as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `undefined` returned by a Node terminal is coming from the `console.log()` call itself. The first line contains the printed value which is `18/09/2023, 12:29:32`, and the second line is a value **returned** by the `.log()` method which is indeed `undefined` because `console.log()` does not return anything special.

If you want to check the value of the `dt` variable in the Node terminal, just type

```
> dt
'18/09/2023, 12:29:32'
```

`console.log()` will always add `undefined`.

---

And as for the first issue, you have a typo

`timeZone` should be `timezone`.